# Dev C++ Crashing with OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, windows-xp, dev-c++

I'm writing a simple algorithm to convert a RGB image, from my webcam, to HSV, it's compiling fine, but crashes when the .exe is executed.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
     // Cria uma janela.
    cvNamedWindow("imagem", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    // Cria a conexão com a webcam.
    CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    // Variável que armazena o frame.
    IplImage *frame;
    IplImage* imghsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);
    while(1)
        {
        // Variável  recebe o frame.
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if(!frame) break;
        cvCvtColor(frame, imghsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        // Exibe o frame na janela.
        cvShowImage("imagem", frame);
        cvShowImage("hsv", imghsv);
        // Encerra o loop com uma tecla.
        if( cvWaitKey(100) == 27 ) break;
    }
    // Libera a memória utiliazada.
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    cvReleaseImage(&imghsv);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    // Fecha a janela.
    cvDestroyWindow("imagem");
    cvDestroyWindow("hsv");
}
```

Without the line "IplImage* imghsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);" the .exe works, but the algorithm only shows my image.

I'm using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 and OpenCV 2.1 in Windows XP SP3.
Sorry about the english.
Thanks

**The problem was solved replacing  `IplImage *frame;` by  `IplImage *frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);`.**

Comment: Ya both are same.. The second image doest know the size of frame. Please have a look at my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
IplImage *frame;
IplImage* imghsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);
```

Your `frame` image has not been yet allocated, you shouldn't create your hsv image before actually grabbing a frame.

*Also note :*

```
cvReleaseImage(&frame);
```

You should not release an image grabbed from `cvQueryFrame()`, OpenCV will take care of it.

From the OpenCV documentation :

> The function cvQueryFrame grabs a frame from a camera or video file, decompresses it and returns it. This function is just a combination of GrabFrame and RetrieveFrame , but in one call. **The returned image should not be released or modified by the user**. In the event of an error, the return value may be NULL.

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
```

You should also check the return value of `cvCreateCameraCapture`, which could be `NULL`.

```
IplImage* imghsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);
```

You should use `IPL_DEPTH_8U` instead of `8`.

Comment: The problem of crashing is becoz of the initialization of the second image. Please have a look..

Comment: @2vision2 true, but that's not the only problem in that code.

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly... Some lines missing in your code... Have a look.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
     // Cria uma janela.
    cvNamedWindow("imagem", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("hsv", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);  // added in orig code
    // Cria a conexão com a webcam.
    CvCapture *capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    // Variável que armazena o frame.
    IplImage *frame;
    IplImage* imghsv;
//    IplImage* imghsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);
    while(1)
        {
        // Variável  recebe o frame.
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        imghsv = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),8,3);  /// changed from orig code.
        if(!frame) break;
        cvCvtColor(frame, imghsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        // Exibe o frame na janela.
        cvShowImage("imagem", frame);
        cvShowImage("hsv", imghsv);
        // Encerra o loop com uma tecla.
        if( cvWaitKey(100) == 27 ) break;
    }
    // Libera a memória utiliazada.
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
    cvReleaseImage(&imghsv);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    // Fecha a janela.
    cvDestroyWindow("imagem");
    cvDestroyWindow("hsv");
}
```

Comment: You should focus your answer on what you *actually* changed in the code. That would help seeing what's wrong in the OP.

Comment: @zakinster Agreed! and fixed.\